# javascript, select color of text with dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to change the color of the input text with a dropdown menu but it doesnt work. Please help

```js
function selectColor()
{ 
  var color = document.getElementById('colours').value;
  document.getElementById("text1").style.color = color;
}
```

```html
<h3>Text Colour: 
  <select id="colours">
    <option value="None" onclick = "selectColor()"> 
    <option value="red" onclick = "selectColor()" >Red
    <option value="green" onclick = "selectColor()">Green
    <option value="blue" onclick = "selectColor()">Blue
    <option value="pink" onclick = "selectColor()">Pink
  </select>
</h3>
<p id="text1">Text color</p>
```

Comment: You need to put your javascript in script tags, for starters.

Comment: it is i just didnt put them here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things:

- use script tags
- prefer the `onchange` event for `select` tag
- add the tag with `text1` id, span, div, paragraph, your choice.

```html
<script>
function selectColor()
{ 
var color = document.getElementById('colours').value;
document.getElementById("text1").style.color = color;


}
</script>

<h3>Text Colour: 
    <select id="colours" onchange="selectColor();">
      <option value="None"></option>
      <option value="red">Red</option>
      <option value="green">Green</option>
      <option value="blue">Blue</option>
      <option value="pink">Pink</option>
    </select>
  </h3>
   <span id="text1">Color selected!</span>
```

Comment: I would also add that you need to close your `option` tags, do not include your select box inside of your `h3` tag, and maybe change your first value from "None" to "black".

Answer (score 2):

See now, I'm a huge fan of unobtrusive javascript. If at all possible, I will separate out the script from the HTML. Below, there's a H3 and a select, and the script itself defines the event handler.

```js
document.getElementById("colours").onchange = selectColor;

function selectColor()
{ 
var color = document.getElementById('colours').value;
document.getElementById("text1").style.color = color;


}
```

```html
<h3 id="text1">Text Colour: </h3>
    <select id="colours">
      <option value="None"> 
      <option value="red"  >Red
      <option value="green">Green
      <option value="blue" >Blue
      <option value="pink" >Pink
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple problems Some said in another answers.

1.Close your option tags.

2.Set the first option **disabled** (it's better)

Use this

```js
function selectColor()
{ 
var color = document.getElementById('colours').value;
document.getElementById("text1").style.color = color;


}
```

```html
<h3 id="text1">Text Colour:</h3> 
    <select id="colours" onchange="selectColor()">
      <option value="None" disabled="disabled" >Select</option> 
      <option value="red"  >Red</option>
      <option value="green">Green</option>
      <option value="blue">Blue</option>
      <option value="pink">Pink</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

### See Below Example.

You need to use "setAttribute" :)

```js
function selectColor()
{ 
var color = document.getElementById('colours').value;
document.getElementById("text1").setAttribute('style', 'color:'+color);

}
```

```html
<h3>Text Colour: 
    <select id="colours" onchange="selectColor();">
      <option value="None" > 
      <option value="red"  >Red
      <option value="green" ">Green
      <option value="blue" ">Blue
      <option value="pink" ">Pink
    </select>
  </h3>
   <span id="text1">Color selected!</span>
```

Comment: You really don't. El.style.color = ... is perfectly acceptable.